# Grammar generating specific language

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, context-sensitive

Construct a context-sensitive grammar that generates L:

```
L = {a^n b^m c^k|k>n, k>m}
```

I believe my productions should go along this lines:

```
S-> ABCC
A-> a|aBC|BC
B-> b|bBC
C-> c|Cc
CB->BC
```

The idea is to start with 2 c and keep always one more c, and then with C->c|Cc ad as much c as i want. 
How can my production for C remember the numbers of m and n.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** Can you figure out a regular grammar such that for any $k, m, n$ with $k > n$ and $k > m$, there is a word in its language with that number of `a`, `b` and `c` (in any order)?

**Hint.** Did you know that you can sort with a context sensitive grammar? See [an example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-sensitive_grammar#Examples) for inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
// end of string marker X
S := TX

// sets up the count relationships
T := TT | AC | BC | C

// sets up the order relationships
BA := AB
CA := AC
CB := BC

// convert to terminals from back to front
Aa := aa
Ab := ab
Ac := ac
Bb := bb
Bc := bc
Cc := cc
CX := c
```